# How to save file for input type "file" for Jenkins Active Choices reactive reference parameter plugin

Tags: jenkins

How to save file for input type "file" for Jenkins Active Choices reactive reference parameter plugin?

Here is the groovy script (I am using freestyle job)

```
return '''
  <label for="uploadFile" >Upload CSV/XLSX file: </label>
  <input name="value" id="uploadFile" type="file" value="" placeholder="upload" class="setting-input" >
'''
```

[My current Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE0Hf.png)

After I choose file and submit nothing gets stored in workspace folder. And when I try to access the variable `params` or `uploadFile`, it is blank.

So how do I achieve this in both freestyle and pipeline script.